# Concatenating string plus numeric value of html element to increment a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of counters I want to increment as images are clicked. When the image is clicked I get the value attr of the image. I can then show the appropriate image in a div with name and all and I want to increment it's responding counter. here is the code:

```
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
var counter3 = 0;
var counter4 = 0;

$('body').click(function(e) {

    var target = $(e.target); // Which cat was clicked
    value = target.attr("value");
    counter = "counter"+ value;
    console.log(counter);
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    $("img").attr({src:"./images/cat" + value +".png"});
    $("h5").html("Cat " + value);
    $("p").html(counter);
});
```

The issue I'm having is that counter = counter1 for example but when I do a counter++ I get NaN. If I just use:

```
counter1++; // or any other counter
```

It increments the global counter variable fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is `counter` initialized?

Comment: It's set as a global variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this!

```
//store in array
var counter[1]=0,counter[2]=0,counter[3]=0,counter[4]=0;

//increment the value
counter[value]++;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
counter = "counter"+ value;
counter++;
```

This is what you are doing wrong. In the first line, you are appending the string "counter" with a number (3, for example), so the result is also a string ("counter3", for example). 
Now in line 2, you are trying to increment that.
This obviously wont work because a string does not increment.

You should do something like what @Ish has mentioned. Something like this:

```
//store in array
var counter[1]=0,counter[2]=0,counter[3]=0,counter[4]=0;

$('body').click(function(e) {

    var target = $(e.target); // Which cat was clicked
    value = target.attr("value");
;
    //increment the value
    counter[parseInt(value)]++;

    $("img").attr({src:"./images/cat" + value +".png"});
    $("h5").html("Cat " +  value);
    $("p").html("counter"+ value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `counter` contains string `"counter1"`, and it's **Not A Number (NaN)**.

You can't use variable variables in `javascript` like you can in `php`...

To achieve what you need, use following:

```
eval(counter + '++;');
```

this is evaluates to string `"counter1++;"` and executes as `javascript` code.

Comment: I don't recommend to use `eval()`. `eval()` is evil :) :)

Comment: It depends on how to use it =) but yes... in certain circumstances it may be used for XSS

Answer (score 0):

NaN means "Not a Number" so you cannot add strings in Javascript. . Why don't you increase the value only and concat counter later.

```
 .....
 counter = value;
 console.log("counter: " + counter);
 counter++; 
 console.log("counter: " + counter);
 ...
 $("p").html("counter"+value);
 ...
```

I can see you are using `counter` in only 1 place (`html()`)  so just concat counter and value  with `+` at the end.